# Simple ceiling function problem

Tags: number-theory, functions, inequality

Prove that $\lceil4n/3\rceil\le 4\lceil n/3\rceil$ for all integers $n$. Try to generalize this result to something where something other than 4 and 3 are used.

Comment: Quoting a homework problem without adding _anything_ of your own does not constitute a question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  you might think about the fact that all integers can be expressed as either $3k, 3k+1$, or $3k+2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\lceil n+n/3\rceil=n+\lceil n/3\rceil$